# Query for Neo4j database in on Rails console

Tags: neo4j, jrubyonrails

Best practice to test your rails application code is on console. I am using Neo4j database on rails, I have node called Customer for which and some other nodes on querying Customer. `find(id)` for some ID I am getting nil on rails console but actually that node is not empty.

On Rails console:

```
jruby-1.6.5 :039 >   a = Customer.find(41)
=> nil 
jruby-1.6.5 :040 >
```

On `Neo4j console`: where `Customer(45)` does not contain any thing.

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ ls
*_db_version =[43]
(me) --[Customer]-> (45)
(me) --[User]-> (2,9)
(me) --[UserType]-> (2,6)
(me) --[Neo4j::Rails::Model]-> (10)
(me) --[Party]-> (46)
(me) --[Searchable]-> (11)
(me) --[Invoice]-> (61)
(me) --[Company]-> (1,8)
(me) --[Currency]-> (3,2)
```

But when I go inside `Company(1,8)`
I can see the records of all Customer

Comment: Not sure. Does Neo4j::Node.load(42) work ?  Do you have a complete example or test for it ?

Comment: Thank you so much Andreas Ronge,Yes it did work,But i did not understand why i cannot see any record on neo4j console inside the [Customer]-> (45) even if it is not empty.

Comment: Strange, Customer.find(41) should do the same as Neo4j::Node.load(42)

Comment: I did Neo4j::Node(41) to find customer, where 41 is the id of the customer,and Neo4j::Node(42) gave me some other node called Contact whose id is 42.